# I am getting the following error while accessing an angularJS app with jasmine: “Can't find variable: angular”

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular

Comment: angular.js may not have been included, pls post more details

Answer (score 1):

In your karma.conf.js you will need to include the path to the javascript files. It looks like the angular file is not in the path/s:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'app/scripts/vendor/angular.js'
]
```